# Android swtich compat icon?

Tags: android, switchcompat

I need to create the switch as the below image
[image: Required]

I have both on and off images for it. I implemented them as

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/swtichTournament"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:showText="false"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_selector"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:checked="false" />
```

The selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" />
<item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" />
```

This is what I get

[image: My OUTPUT]

As you can see there is some extra color which is not required. How do I remove that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the AppCompat library, replace your switch element by a SwitchCompat element and you'll get what you want.
For more info about switchCompat, please see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html

Comment: Thanx it works but I am experiencing some issue. please check the question

Comment: remove the thumb attribute, you can theme the widget using themes.

Comment: use colorControlActivated for the ON color and colorSwitchThumbNormal for the OFF color

Answer (score 2):

You can set Switch's background to transparent in your XML:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this link will be  help you
https://androidician.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/android-custom-toggle-button-example-ios-like-toggle-buttons/